# Using Spring Data with PostgreSQL JsonB type properties

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm having hard time trying to use PostgreSQL with JsonB data type in Spring Data. I have the following table:

```
create table mytable (
  ...
  MYDATA JsonB not null,
  ...
);
```

Then, I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
...
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class MyEntity {
  ...
    @NotNull
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "MYDATA", nullable = false)
    private MyAbstractData myAbstractData;
    ...
}
```

MyAbstractData is defined as follows:

```
...
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = MyConcreteData.class, name = "data")
})
...
public abstract class MyAbstractData implements Serializable {
    private String key;
    ...
}
```

Last but not least, MyConcreteData looks like below:

```
public class MyConcreteData extends MyAbstractData {
...
}
```

My repository is as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
  public Optional<MyEntity> findByIdAndSomething (Long id, Something something);
}
```

In the database, I'm able to insert the value, for example, '{"type":"data","key":"i1"}' but, doing the following:

```
Optional<MyEntity> myEntity = myEntityRepo.findByIdAndSomething(1L, something);
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given string value: "{\"type\":\"data\",\"key\":\"i1\"}" cannot be transformed to Json object; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given string value: "{\"type\":\"data\",\"key\":\"i1\"}" cannot be transformed to Json object
```

However, I'm able to serialize/deserialize successfully the class MyConcreteData using the fasterxml ObjectMapper and to create a valid JsonNode from the string "{"type":"data","key":"i1"}".

I know that my case might be difficult to follow but I'm still hoping that someone could help.

Many thanks in advance.

Seymour

Comment: Just to mention that, as opposed to what I stated here, the mentioned exception raises during integration tests, while using H2 database. So it doesn't appear with PostgreSQL, as stated, but with H2, during integration tests. Which shouldn't be a problem neither as H2 supports JsonB, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. In order to get working the sample shown above, the script used to insert data test in the H2 database should use FORMAT JSON syntax, for example:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (..., MYDATA, ...)
  VALUES (..., '{"type":"data","key":"i1"}' FORMAT JSON,...);
```

So, the clue here is to use FORMAT JSON immediately after the JSON payload in the insert statement. This way the find operation done by Spring Data works as expected.